# The dimension '[Time]' was not found in the cube when the string [Time].[Year], was parsed

Tags: ssas-2012

[Time].[Year] attribute's defaultMember property is set to

```
    tail(FILTER( [Date].[Year].members, 
        not  ISEMPTY( [Date].currentmember )), 1).item(0)
```

When I try to browse the cube, I am getting an error:

DefaultMember(Date,Year) (1,14) The dimension '[Time]' was not found in the cube when the string [Time].[Year], was parsed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an odd message considering the expression that you show has the Date dimension and not the Time dimension specified. If that's truly the case, here's what I would do to track down the problem. Find the solution folder in the file system, open the project folder, and then open the bin folder. You should have a file with an ASDATABASE file extension. If you don't see file extensions, but see a column for type, open the one with the Analysis Services Database Deployment Contents type. Open it with Notepad or your favorite text or XML editor. Search the file for [Time].[Year] and then work your way backwards through the nodes to figure out which property of which dimension it belongs to. Then you can go into SSDT and fix the problem.

Comment: I can't find [Time].[Year] in a database. Ended up restoring cube from old backup.